# Two cables that dissipate the same heat the same?

Tags: power, heat

Suppose we have two conductors which dissipate 10W, one is copper and the other is aluminum. Will both heat the same and do it at the same time? Assume the external heat dissipation is equal for both conductors.

Comment: No. As one has higher conductivity, the other will have different cross sectional area to compensate. This gives different thermal inertia so they won't heat in exactly the same way.

Comment: You have not specified anything about the cables. Are they the same weight? Or the same diameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **temperature** of an electrically heated conductor will stabilise when **heat lost to it surroundings = power in**.

If the conductors are the same length and the same resistance then the aluminium conductor will have a larger diameter than the copper conductor as copper has a higher conductivity. That means the aluminium conductor will have a larger surface area to radiate heat. I would expect that at steady state the aluminium conductor will run cooler.

> ... assuming the external heat dissipation is equal for both conductors ...

If they're both dissipating 10 W then they must be the same.